# System-global counter that can be updated programmatically (on various Linux versions)?

Tags: c, linux, cgi, counter

I need some fast method to update key/value type data or alternatively an arbitrary amount of "counters" system-wide on Linux. The systems in question are Ubuntu 10.04, RHEL 4.8 and RHEL 5.x.

Now, I am aware of memcached, but it seems to be more suited for long-running processes, such as FastCGI processes. Unfortunately my process is a traditional CGI and therefore has to use some persistent storage outside of the process itself.

What options do I have and which are easiest and *cheapest* (w.r.t. runtime) to access from C/C++?

Note: this is not to measure the speed (i.e. performance counters) but to measure the number a certain type of event happens. And in order to count reliably, I need to be able to atomically increment the counters at will ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple [DBM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dbm)-like database, for example [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/).

Comment: Thanks. The documentation abotu GDBM makes no mentioning of atomicity, though. So how will this behave with concurrent CGI instances trying to up the same counter? What about ACID?

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED Check the other databases in the Wikipedia article. Some of them have atomicity and/or ACID handling. I think most of the DBM-family are much lighter than the modern "NoSQL" databases they inspired.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a small SQLite database. SQLite is FAST and reliable, any application can modify it and a transaction method prevents collision. Just add a record to a table for each event, or use a single table with an [event] column. Inserting is really fast, what's slow is searching, but you'll only search when analysing the data, hopefully AFTER the performance is a factor.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the data will be completely independently read. Likely not even on the same machine, so a portable format lends itself (I understand even the binary format of SQLite is largely portable across versions and definitely across architectures).

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, in order

> to update key/value type data

Developers often use [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) databases. They run mainly on linux systems, and some of them are in C++ ([MongoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) & [ClusterPoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clusterpoint)). They are really fast for this kind of things, they try really hard to keep low latency and it should be easy to access it from C++ since they are coded in C++.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but won't the fact that each of the spawned instances has to establish a connection be a big issue?  What about ACID?

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED I know more about MongoDB than ClusterPoint, but you can do atomic increments within a command against a value, you can also use connection pooling to limit having to establish a cold connection for every request.  I'm uncertain, but think Redis might be better for this particular use case though... that or having a simple service that uses persistant storage to a file that only contains a binary encoded 64bit unsigned integer.